# ios UIButton tap issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have added two `UIButton` named buttonA and buttonB as `SubView`. When I tap `buttonA`, `handleButtonA` function is called as expected, but when I tap `buttonB`, `handleButtonA` and `handleButtonB` both are called. Can not understand how to fix this issue. Here is code.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var buttonA: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.setTitle("buttonA", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        btn.backgroundColor = .green
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonA), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    lazy var buttonB: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        btn.setTitle("buttonB", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonB), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    @objc func handleButtonA() {
        print("buttonA tapped")
    }

    @objc func handleButtonB() {
        print("buttonB tapped")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configUI()
    }

    func configUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(buttonA)
        buttonA.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.left.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            $0.height.width.equalTo(80)
        }

        view.addSubview(buttonB)
        buttonB.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            $0.height.width.equalTo(80)
        }
    }
}
```

it's so weird,when I write configUI function  like this, it's works fine .

```
func configUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(buttonA)
    buttonA.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.left.equalToSuperview()
        $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-1)
        $0.height.width.equalTo(80)
    }

    view.addSubview(buttonB)
    buttonB.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        $0.height.width.equalTo(80)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello buttonA.snp what is snp here .??

Comment: i have check this it's working fine for me i think the issue is your constrain or may be equalSuperview !! Please check your constrain function snap issue is there not in button tap okay !!

Comment: can you test in a real device sometimes this issue happen with me when i use simulator with a older mac it automatically tap the button due to lagging.

Comment: buttonA snap code like this,its works ok.
$0.left.equalToSuperview()
$0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-1)